# Grouped Select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple question really - how do I use the select(ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper) with grouped options?

I have got it working with a select_tag (ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper) but I would really like to have it using a select tag to match the rest of the form.  Is this possible?

My options look like this:

```
[
  ['Group 1', ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]],
  ['Group 2',["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]]
]
```

whilst my view is currently:

```
%tr#expense
  %td
    = f.text_field :value
    = f.hidden_field :type, :value => mode
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit**

Correction, since you're using Arrays you'll need [grouped_options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001630)

Example:

```
grouped_options = [
  ['Group 1',
    ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]],
  ['Group 2',
    ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]]
]
grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options)
```

Prints the following:

```
<optgroup label="Group 1">
  <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 2">
  <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
</optgroup>
```

Note that you have to provide your own **select** tags to wrap this. There is no **select** function that will do grouping for you, just this method.

You should get over your reticence. The Rails Way (tm) to do what you ask is to use select_tag with grouped_options_for_select:

```
<%= select_tag "foo[bar]", 
grouped_options_for_select(@bars) %>
```

This is what happens when you go off the beaten path with Rails. :)

Here's a reference I just found on google:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185407

Comment: Do you have an example of this in practice?  I saw this in the docs, but cannot figure out how to get it working.

Comment: This is also fine, except that it doesn't work with a traditional select.  I'm reticent to use select_tag, and it means I need to try and work out the name of the element on the fly.

Comment: Looks as though there is a helper method for building a select tag with grouped options in the latest Rails: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a Hash instead of nested arrays:

```
grouped_options = {
 'North America' => [['United States','US'], 'Canada'],
 'Europe' => ['Denmark','Germany','France']
}


<%= select_tag "foo[bar]", 
grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, 'Denmark') %>
```

Here, there is also a selected option ('Denmark')