# grouped_collection_select on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I show this select as grouped collection select. I tried various different type and it did not work. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
<%= f.select :agency_type_id, AgencyType.joins(:sector).order('sectors.name ASC, name ASC').map {|atype| ["#{atype.sector.name}  -  #{atype.name}", atype.id]}, :prompt => "Select Sector  -  Agency Type" %>
```

I would like to show by grouped sector followed by Agency Type. 
For Example:
Big Bend 
   Federal LEA
   Local LEA
Del Rio 
   Federal LEA
   Local LEA
and so on...

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192862/687142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with API, I got the solutions:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :agency_type_id, Sector.order('name ASC'), :agency_types, :name, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select Agency Type" %>
```