# How do I split options from a collection into different categories within the select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

Here's the haml select2 markup:

```
 = select_tag "v_friend_id",
     options_from_collection_for_select(
       @v_friends, :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id
     ),
     :include_blank => true,
     :class => "compare-search",
     :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px;"
```

These users have a boolean 'isRunning' on the backend. I need to make two different groups with the lables 'running' (if isRunning == true) and 'citizen' if not true.

How could I do that with select2. Is there anyway to pass the dasta back to JS and push it to an array? would that be the way to go?

here's my current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.compare-search').prepend('<option/>').val(function () {
      return $(this).val('');
    });

    $(".compare-search").select2({
      placeholder: "Search to compare",
      allowClear: true
    });

    $('.compare-search').on('change', function() {

      if (! $(this).val().length) {
        $('.vScoreExplain').show();
        $('.stats').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('.vScoreExplain').hide();
        $('.stats').show();
      }
    });
});
```

[image: I want it to look like this, but my specified categories instead of timezones]

### I want it to look like this, but my specified categories instead of timezones ^

TLDR:
Right now, I'm able to search and select all 'friends', however, I want to divide them into groups based on the 'isRunning' boolean from the backend, similarly to how the photo on the bottom of my post splits into groups of different timezones. Let me know if that doesn't make sense. I can try to make it sound more concise.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Right now, I'm able to search and select all 'friends', however, I want to divide them into groups based on the 'isRunning' boolean from the backend, similarly to how the photo on the bottom of my post splits into groups of different timezones.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense. I can try to make it sound more concise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouped Select in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192843/grouped-select-in-rails)