# Rails how to create select dropdown with double nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to create a select dropdown for menu items. The complicated part is each Restaurant has many Categories which have many menu items. My goal is to have a dropdown that prints something like the following:

```
<optgroup label="Category 1">
  <option value="menu_item 1">Menu Item 1</option>
  <option value="menu_item 2">Menu Item 2</option>
  <option value="menu_item 3">Menu Item 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Category 2">
  <option value="menu_item 1">Menu Item 1</option>
  <option value="menu_item 2">Menu Item 2</option>
  <option value="menu_item 3">Menu Item 3</option>
  <option value="menu_item 4">Menu Item 4</option>
</optgroup>
```

Here are my models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :restaurant
  has_many :menus, dependent: :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meals, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :category
end
```

Before I added in the Category model I had the following to create my Meal object:

```
<%= form_for [@customer,@meal] do |f| %>
 <%=f.collection_select(:food_item,restaurant.menus.all, :name, :name) %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: restaurant.id %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit meal"%>
<%end%>
```

I was trying to figure out a way to do something similar to this [Grouped Select in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192843/grouped-select-in-rails) but I'm not sure how exactly with the extra model involved. Let me know if I need to include any additional information and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try changing it to `<%=f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, Category.all, restaurant.menus.all, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: @Josh have look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Comment: @Pavan Thanks for your quick response! I think you're close, but the menus are nested inside of each Category, not the Restaurants anymore. So instead of restaurant.menus.all it would have to be something like category.menus.all, but I'm not sure how to make sure I do that for each instance of Category

Comment: Ok. Try this `<%=f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, Category.all, Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.menus ] }, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: @Pavan that get's me really close, but causes this error `[#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Menu id: 36, name: "Mushroom Pizza", meal_type: nil, details: "Locally grown mushrooms", restaurant_id: 18, category_id: 5>]>]] is not a symbol nor a string` I think that's because it's c.menus and c.menus.name?

Comment: Ok. Now try this `<%=f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, Category.all, Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.menus.name, c.menus.id ] }, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: @Pavan tried this `<%=f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories.all, restaurant.categories.all.collect {|c| [ c.menus.name, c.menus.id ] }, :name, :id, :name) %>` but I get `undefined method id for #<Menu::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fed2b50e2e8>` Tried to get do it without the id, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ok. Got it. Try this now. `<%=f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories.all, restaurant.categories.menus.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: @Pavan `undefined method menus for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help and was able to get it to work with this!

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories, :menus,    :name, :name, :name) %>
```

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select